# Formula that will skip one column when calculating SUM() or similar functions

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to run a =SUM(A1:G1), but always skip one column, regardless if it has value or not.
In this case, it should calculate A1+C1+E1+G1.

Is there another function I could append to SUM() or other similar functions as SUM in order to skip one column?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question mentions **one** column, but your example skips **three** columns *(B, D, F)*.....which do you want ??

Comment: pls dont mix tags of two similar but totally different aplications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:G1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7}))))
```

Or with Excel O365:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:G1,{1,3,5,7}))
```

---

A bit more of a general solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(COLUMN(A1:G1),2)*A1:G1)
```

Or with Excel O365:

```
=SUM(MOD(COLUMN(A1:G1),2)*A1:G1)
```

Or even:

```
=SUM(INDEX(1:1,SEQUENCE(4,,1,2)))
```

---

Since you included `Google-Sheets`, I'll throw in an option using `QUERY()`:

```
=SUM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(1:1),"Select * skipping 2"))
```

Maybe a bit more verbose, but very understandable IMO.

Comment: I voted yours as the best answer because it contained the QUERY() for Google Spreadsheets. Thank you, JvdV!

Answer (score 3):

Using the following method you can calculate any number of alternate columns, without the need of manual `+`

Suppose your data is in second row onwards, use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:G2, MOD(COLUMN(A2:G2),2))
```

Simply a `sumproduct` of `cell values` and a `array` of {1,0,1,0,1...}

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another slight variation

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:G2*ISODD(COLUMN(A2:G2)))
```

[image]

But if the even columns contain letters instead of numbers this will give an error, so you can use instead

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(+A1:G1)*ISODD(COLUMN(A1:G1)))
```

Comparing @AnilGoyal's answer, this works as well

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:G1,--ISODD(COLUMN(A1:G1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider something of the format:

```
=SUM(A1:G1)-INDEX(A1:G1,2)
```

[image]

The *2* in the formula means remove the 2<sup>nd</sup> item in the part of the row. *(so the **999** is dropped)*

So the formula `=SUM(BZ10:ZZ10)-INDEX(BZ10:ZZ10,2)` drops **CA10** from the sum, etc.
*(a similar formula can be constructed for columns)*

Comment: I think you might have misread the question a bit =). OP wants to skip multiple columns.

Comment: @JvdV  you are correct....the text mentions **one column**, but this example indicates several columns

Answer (score 1):

## google sheets:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(N(A1:H3), 1*ISODD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:H)))))
```

[image]

```
=INDEX(IF(ISODD(COLUMN(A:H)), TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(A1:H3*ISODD(COLUMN(A:H)), 0)), 1^ROW(A1:A3))), ))
```

[image]